# Using different context managers depending on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, contextmanager

Is it possible to execute a single block using different context managers depending on some condition?

Example:

```
if some_condition:
    with ContextManager(**args) as contex:
        ... # some block
else:
    with OtherContextManager(**other_args) as contex:
        ... # the same block
```

One way would be to wrap `...` into a function, but this may not be too convenient in my case. Is there another possibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the constructed object in a variable, like:

```
if some_condition:
    cm = ContextManager(**args)
else:
    cm = OtherContextManager(**other_args)

with cm as contex:
        ... # some block
```

The above can easily be extended to three possible context managers, etc. You can also decide for example to first "patch" the context manager before "entering" the context.

Although it is common to see a pattern like `with foo() as bar:`, in fact Python simply evaluates the `foo()`, obtains that element, and calls `.__enter__()` on the object. The result of that method is stored in the `bar`.

So there is nothing "special" about the `foo()` *call*, you can use any kind of object on the left side. You can thus for example encapsulate the `if`-`else` logic in a separate function, and return the context manager, and then use the variable, or pass context managers as parameters. As long as you use it in a `with` statement, Python will call `.__enter__(..)` and `.__exit__(..)` behind the curtains.

Comment: Does this always work as intended? Suppose `cm = open(file1, 'rb') if some_condition else open(file2, 'rb')`. In this case, would `with cm as f:` still ensure that the file gets closed properly in case of an exception? At least `SIM115` seems to think otherwise...

Comment: @Bob: yes, since we only open one file, depending on the condition, and that is the one that we `__enter__`.

Comment: @Bob: you can test this by making a custom context processor that for example only prints for `__enter__` and `__exit__`, after all, this is basically what happens, except that for a file context processor, it has of course logic to open and close the file properly, whereas for a context processor you write, you can handle it in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
with ContextManager(**args) if some_condition else OtherContextManager(**other_args) as contex:
    ... # some block
```

...?

Answer (score 2):

We can just go crazy and take advantage of the fact that both `__enter__` and `__exit__` are just methods and that they're called in the original object (not the one returned by `__enter__`):

```
class WrapperContext:

 def __init__(self, condition):
     if condition:
         self.real_context = ContextA()
     else:
         self.real_context = ContextB()

 def __enter__(self):
     return self.real_context.__enter__()

 def __exit__(self):
     return self.real_context.__exit__()
```

and use it like this:

```
 with WrapperContext(condition) as obj:
```